# User password not encrypted when using FOSUserBundle + EasyAdminBundle with Symfony 3.4

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle, password-encryption, easyadmin

I use **Symfony 3.4** with **FOSUserBundle** and **EasyAdminBundle**.

I've been stuck for a while on the following problem: when I create a new user via EasyAdmin, the password entered is not hashed, it remains clear in the database and in the edit form of the created user (in EasyAdmin), while there is no problem when I create a user via the form generated by FOSUserBundle (register).

My **User entity** :

```
<?php
// src/Repas/UserBundle/Entity/User.php

namespace Repas\UserBundle\Entity;

use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="fos_user")
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;
}
```

My **AdminController.php** file :

```
<?php
namespace Repas\MenusBundle\Controller;

use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Controller\AdminController as BaseAdminController;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\PasswordType;

class AdminController extends BaseAdminController
{
    public function createNewUserEntity()
    {
        return $this->get('fos_user.user_manager')->createUser();
    }

    public function persistUserEntity($user)
    {
        $this->get('fos_user.user_manager')->updateUser($user, false);
        parent::persistEntity($user);
    }

    public function updateUserEntity($user)
    {
        $this->get('fos_user.user_manager')->updateUser($user, false);
        parent::updateEntity($user);
    }
}
```

In my **config.yml** file :

```
easy_admin:
    entities:
        User:
            class: Repas\UserBundle\Entity\User
            export_path: '%kernel.root_dir/../var/export/user'
            password_encoding: { algorithm: 'bcrypt', cost: 12 }
```

In my **security.yml** file :

```
encoders:
        Repas\UserBundle\Entity\User: bcrypt
```

In my **routing.yml** file :

```
fos_user:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/all.xml"
easy_admin_bundle:
    resource: "@RepasMenusBundle/Controller/AdminController.php"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /admin
```

I've been through many forums, as well as the official docs, I think I followed everything properly but I certainly missed something.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The EasyAdminBundle doesn't define an option to encrypt the password, it only provides options to save the entities (a crud) which you can extend by [defining custom actions](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/EasyAdminBundle/tutorials/custom-actions.html) based on routes or actions inside an overrided [AdminController in order to integrate with FOSUserBundle](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/EasyAdminBundle/integration/fosuserbundle.html).

> Example

```
easy_admin:
    entities:
        User:
            list:
                actions:
                    - { name: 'create_user', type: 'route' } //or nothing on type to use the action option
```

At this point you already have either a defined controller accessible by route or an overriden controller which handles the specified User actions. You only need to use the FOSUser methods to encrypt the password properly, as read in [this doc](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/EasyAdminBundle/integration/fosuserbundle.html#creating-new-users).

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I already have an overriden controller (AdminController.php) in which I already have inserted the FOSUser methods as mentionned in the doc you linked. You can see it in the sample code I pasted in my first post. So I think I have already done what you suggest, unless I did not understand your suggestion ;-)

Comment: I guess I have found the solution as mentionned in my last post. I will tell you.

Comment: Yes, I saw your controller but not the easy admin config pointing that controller as route or action(your easy admin config doesn't has that config). That's my post reason If you have a config file please add it in order to give you a proper answer

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I guess my mistake is that in the form generated by Easyadmin to create a new user, Easyadmin generates a field named "password" instead of "plainPassword" which is the one FOSUser uses to encrypt the entered password. So I think I just have to create a new "plainPassword" field in my "Easyadmin new user" form and enter the user password in that field to encrypt it. Then the encrypted password will be stored in "password" field of the database.

I will tell you if that is the solution.

Comment: If you are using FosUser and extending `FOS\UserBundle\Model\User` you already have a plainPassword field

Comment: Yes but it is not displayed in the Easyadmin form. I have to add it manually.